# Show All Events

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am using the Kendo UI Scheduler. I have the Agenda view, which is nice. But I would like to show ALL the events in the Calendar - starting from the first Event added and going to the last - and the Agenda view seems to only show 1 week's worth of events.

I would like something that resembles the List view in Outlook.
[image: Outlook List View]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion on this in the [Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/extending-agenda-view-to-show-whole-month-or-above-).

In this discussion, an answer is given with a link to a [demo](http://output.jsbin.com/ucaB/1) in which a custom agenda view is implemented. This view shows all events in the next 31 days:

```
var CustomAgenda = kendo.ui.AgendaView.extend({    
    endDate: function() {
        var date = kendo.ui.AgendaView.fn.endDate.call(this);
        return kendo.date.addDays(date, 31);
    }
});
```

In the scheduler options you add this view using this configuration:

```
views: [
    "day",
    { type: "week", selected: true },    
    // "agenda",
    { type: CustomAgenda, title: "Custom Agenda" }
]
```

If you navigate to the date of the first event and change the custom agenda view to show events (last_event_date - first_event_date) days forward, you get what you wanted to do.